# Scroll vertical funciona pero no muestra los 3 últimos elementos

Tags: html, css

Tengo una `div` contenedor y una lista `ul` con sus respectivos `li` activé el scroll vertical, funciona pero los últimos 3 elementos no se muestran. Cómo puedo corregir este error?

mi lista luce así:

```css
    .container-lista {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .menu-li {
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 36px;
        padding-top: 13px;
        padding-bottom: 13px;
        color: #111111;
    }
```

```html
      <div className="container-lista">
           <ul>
               <li className="menu-li">1</li>
               <li className="menu-li">2</li>
               <li className="menu-li">3</li>
               <li className="menu-li">4</li>
               <li className="menu-li">5</li>
               <li className="menu-li">6</li>
               <li className="menu-li">7</li>
               <li className="menu-li">8</li>
               <li className="menu-li">9</li>
               <li className="menu-li">10</li>
               <li className="menu-li">11</li>
               <li className="menu-li">12</li>
               <li className="menu-li">13</li>
               <li className="menu-li">14</li>
               <li className="menu-li">15</li>
               <li className="menu-li">16</li>
               <li className="menu-li">17</li>
               <li className="menu-li">18</li>
               <li className="menu-li">19</li>
               <li className="menu-li">20</li>
               <li className="menu-li">21</li>
               <li className="menu-li">22</li>
               <li className="menu-li">23</li>
               <li className="menu-li">24</li>
               <li className="menu-li">25</li>
               <li className="menu-li">26</li>
          </ul>
     </div>
```

El scroll funciona, pero no llega hasta el ultimo elemento como lo muestro a continuación:
[image: scrollNotWorking]

Comment: Pues yo reproduje tu ejercicio y los elementos se visualizan bien, ¿desde que dispositivo vez esto?

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna forma de reproducir esto de mejor manera? En el código que compartes se visualiza bien. Probablemente sea que algo está calculando erradamente la altura del contenedor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solo agregue la clase height en tu etiqueta ul

```css
.container-lista {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
ul{
    height: 100%;
}
.menu-li {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 36px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    color: #111111;
}
```

```html
 <div className="container-lista">
       <ul>
           <li className="menu-li">1</li>
           <li className="menu-li">2</li>
           <li className="menu-li">3</li>
           <li className="menu-li">4</li>
           <li className="menu-li">5</li>
           <li className="menu-li">6</li>
           <li className="menu-li">7</li>
           <li className="menu-li">8</li>
           <li className="menu-li">9</li>
           <li className="menu-li">10</li>
           <li className="menu-li">11</li>
           <li className="menu-li">12</li>
           <li className="menu-li">13</li>
           <li className="menu-li">14</li>
           <li className="menu-li">15</li>
           <li className="menu-li">16</li>
           <li className="menu-li">17</li>
           <li className="menu-li">18</li>
           <li className="menu-li">19</li>
           <li className="menu-li">20</li>
           <li className="menu-li">21</li>
           <li className="menu-li">22</li>
           <li className="menu-li">23</li>
           <li className="menu-li">24</li>
           <li className="menu-li">25</li>
           <li className="menu-li">26</li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Estas usando bootstrap? talvez podrias compartir mas de tu html para entrar en contexto, ya que el codigo asi como lo posteaste muestra correctamente los 26 elementos